# Issue With EXPDP Full Tablespace

Tags: oracle, expdp

I am trying to export schema with below command using expdp in Oracle 18c XE , the schema uses tablespace  named "testtablespace"

```
expdp myschema/*******@//localhost:1521/XEPDB1 schemas=myschema directory=DATA_PUMP_DIR dumpfile=myschema.dmp logfile=myschema.log
```

the tablespace "testtablespace" has maximum size of 100MB and currently 70MB of it is utilized , upon running above command I get error

```
ORA-01654: unable to extend index TESTTABLESPACE.SYS_MTABLE_0000357BA_IND_2 by 8 in tablespace testtablespace
```

When I increase size of tablespace size the issue is fixed , it seems like during export the tablespace of schema is being used for some temporary data storage

Is there a way that I can specify a temporary tablespace to be used instead of my schema tablespace so that even if my schema tablespace is completely full it can still export schema using expdp without any issue?

Answer (score 3):

[Tracking Progress Within a Job](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/18/sutil/oracle-data-pump-overview.html#GUID-B9A676E5-B3CB-417B-BC97-65FE33448C2F)

> While the data and metadata are being transferred, a master table is
> used to track the progress within a job.
>
> ...
>
> The master table is created in the schema of the current user
> performing the export or import operation. Therefore, that user must
> have the CREATE TABLE system privilege and a sufficient tablespace
> quota for creation of the master table.

So alter the user performing the export to have another default tablespace. That way the master table will be created in another tablespace.

Comment: Is there a way in expdp through which at the time of export where master tables have to be created

Comment: @ProgNi If such parameter existed, I would have posted that instead of the above.

Comment: Ok , thank you for your answer. I am going for your provided suggestion